# Are epic crafting ingredients farmable?

Tags: god-of-war-2018

Now that I have access to both Muspelheim and Niflheim I have uncovered Epic level armour to craft, which requires the following ingredients.

- Smouldering Ember - Muspelheim
- Mist Echos - Niflheim
- Niflheim Alloy - Niflheim

These seem to be specific to those realms, and are required to both craft and upgrade the armours.

Are these ingredients unlimited in number? Am I able to farm them in order to craft all the available armours and upgrade them all? Or should I save them to craft a single set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Mist Echoes and the Niflheim Alloy are farmeable. I'm not sure about the ingredients from Muspelheim, I didn't get far enough in that realm.

Niflheim is essentially a single dungeon where you can farm forever, and you get Mist Echoes and other Niflheim ingredients as rewards. As far as I understand, you could craft all versions of the Niflheim armor (Ivaldi's), but that might be more farming that you might want. There are some components for the Niflheim set that are finite, but I got enough of them to theoretically craft all three versions of the set.

Comment: The Muspelheim armours seem to start at level 4, and the Niflheim armours start at level 7, so it seems more logical to farm Niflheim.

Comment: @DavidYell I think you need also some Muspelheim ingredients for later upgrades of the Nilfheim armor, so you still might need to do both to get the best gear. (and there is another armor set above those two still)

Comment: The only limited resource from Niflhelm is armor pieces, but you get 9 from Sindri's quest, and you only need 9 (1 per item, 3 sets with 3 items each).

Answer (score 1):

You can infinitely farm any components in Muspelheim (including Surtur's Crest), but you need to unlock this possibility:

- Beat challenges on first 5 arenas (each arena has "Normal" and "Hard" challenges) to access last arena.
- Beat challenge on last arena.
- Beating last arena will unlock "Insane" challenge for each of first 5 arenas.
- Beat 3 "Insane" challenges to get special keys.
- Redeem keys on last arena to access new, repeatable challenge.

This repeatable challenge will allow you to farm embers and other resources indefinitely.

You may not want to get Muspelheim armor once you have Niflheim armor sets, but some of the latter actually require Muspelheim components to upgrade.